# adding jpanel into a jframe. netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

i am particularly using netbeans gui editor and i am new to gui

i have a jframe created and I added jtabbedpanel.

inside the jtabbedpanel i have 2 panels that i call standard and compact

i have set standardPanel = new ImagePanel(); which ImagePanel.java is located on different java file

how am I suppose to put a panel on different file for reusability ?

i obviously dont want all the codes in a single file.

is this the right way to design a gui ?

thanks

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/491367/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/jframe-import-multiple-jpanel

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own class, something like "CustomPanel" that extends from JPanel. You put that class in its own file, and everything that goes on the JPanel should be a part of that class.

Then, instead of adding a JPanel to the tabbed panel, you create an instance of CustomPanel and add it to the tabbed panel.

Comment: yes that is what i did but the problem is now i want to include that jpanel to my jframe class 

my jframe has standardPanel which I want to initialize standardPanel as ImagePanel defined in other class.

let me know if my question is confusing?

Comment: @stdnoit, yes, you've lost me. Please provide sample code, or at least pseudo code of what you have, and what you expect.

Comment: please check my reply as answer on the above. thanks. its  too long to be here. thanks Marcus